# How to pass a custom data bag while bootstrapping a node in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using Chef12  to mange Users and SSH keys.
I have followed this tutorial:
https://blog.chef.io/2014/07/10/managing-users-and-ssh-keys-in-a-hybrid-world/

It worked fine.

Now problem is , user cookbook which was used in this process by default it takes data bag named users.

I have a data bag named users but this time i want to a different set of users which is in a different data bag.

But it takes only data bag name "users".

How can i pass this data bag to be used while bootstrapping a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [README in the users cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users), you will see that you can provide `data_bag` parameter to the `user_manage` resource.

```
users_manage 'GROUPNAME' do
  group_id GROUPID
  action [:create]
  data_bag 'DATABAG_NAME'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Draco.
Saved my efforts.